# How can I compile a single driver/file in OpenBSD without compiling the whole kernel?

Tags: c, driver, openbsd

I have started to write a driver (for the I2C device PCF8574 from NXP) for `OpenBSD`.

Currently I compile the kernel with the official instruction https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq5.html from the OpenBSD page.

But when I change the code of the driver and I type `make`, the whole kernel will be compiled. Not only the changed file. How can I prevent this? How can I compile a single file from the kernel and then link it with the rest of the kernel?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually `make` deals with this. Are you sure that all the kernel gets recompiled? (on Linux this is not the case)

Comment: Yes. The system time was not set correctly, so make rebuilds always the whole kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some parts are always rebuilt but the full kernel is never rebuilt if you use the correct options.

```
# cd /usr/src/sys/arch/amd64/conf
# config GENERIC.MP
# cd ../compile/GENERIC.MP
# make clean
# make -j4
# make install
```

Change any source file in `/usr/src/sys` and then:

```
# cd /usr/src/sys/arch/amd64/compile/GENERIC.MP
# make config
# make -j4
# make install
```

The last `make -j4` will only build the changed files + other necessary files.

Comment: I found the issue why `make` rebuilds the whole kernel. The system time was not set correctly. I use a PINE64 ROCK64 board as test system. I mark your answer as accepted.